# Getting "bad username or password" error while attempting to connect to broker

Tags: node.js, mqtt, auth0

I have followed the tutorial presented [here](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/authenticating-devices-using-mqtt), but I couldn't connect a client to the server. I always get the following error message (full stacktrace):

```
Error: Connection refused: Bad username or password
at MqttClient._handleConnack (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:760:24)
at MqttClient._handlePacket (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:300:12)
at process (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:242:12)
at Writable.writable._write (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:252:5)
at doWrite (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:345:64)
at writeOrBuffer (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:334:5)
at Writable.write (${project_dir}/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:271:11)
at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:528:20)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

I have double-checked my environment variables, whose values came from my Auth0 account, (particularly `CLIENT_ID`, `DOMAIN`, `CLIENT_SECRET` and `CONNECTION`) but they seem fine.

I've changed the client's code a bit to match the current version of MQTT.js. Here is the code:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const settings = {
    port: 1883,
    keepalive: 1000,
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp', // already tried 'MQTT' with protocol version 4
    protocolVersion: 3,
    clientId: 'a random id',
    username: 'an account at Auth0',
    password: 'the password of the account'
}

var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost', settings);

client.on("connect", function () {
    client.subscribe("topic");
    console.log("connected");
});

client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer 
    console.log(message.toString());
    client.end();
});
```

The broker code is very similar to the presented in the tutorial. I want to solve this error before changing it.

```
const mosca = require('mosca')
const Auth0Mosca = require('auth0mosca');
require('dotenv').config();

const settings = {
    port: 1883
};

if (!process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN || !process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID ||
    !process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET || !process.env.AUTH0_CONNECTION) {
    throw 'Make sure you have AUTH0_DOMAIN, AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET and AUTH0_CONNECTION in your .env file';
}

const auth0 = new Auth0Mosca('https://' + process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN, process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, process.env.AUTH0_CONNECTION);

// mosca server
const server = new mosca.Server(settings);

server.authenticate = auth0.authenticateWithCredentials();
server.authorizePublish = auth0.authorizePublish();
server.authorizeSubscribe = auth0.authorizeSubscribe();

server.on('ready', setup);

// MQTT server is ready
function setup() {
    console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
}

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    console.log('New connection: ', client.id);
});
```

I know that it is probably a stupid mistake or a library update that is causing this. For the latter case, here are the versions:

```
"auth0mosca": "^0.1.0",
"mosca": "^2.3.0",
"mqtt": "^2.5.0"
```

Finally, I have checked that the request reaches the broker.

Comment: You probably want to include the code for the broker as well so we can see what it's actually doing to authenticate the user

Comment: Done, thanks for the hint!

Comment: I've found the problem. I've specified RS256 algorithm in Auth0, in the JsonWebToken Signature Algorithm. But, Auth0Mosca doesn't use it to verify the token. I'll  write an  answer here later, for everyone facing the same issue. Sorry for asking something that I could have solved myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [forked](https://github.com/josepaiva94/auth0mosca) the repository with the code of the tutorial and updated its dependencies to the latest versions. Also, added the possibility to verify JWTs signed with, for example, RS256 algorithm.

This solved my problem and I hope it helps everyone facing the same issue.